# How to parse below JSON response?

Tags: android, json, parsing, response

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "1": "Business People",
        "2": "Actors",
        "3": "Musicians",
        "4": "Sports People",
        "5": "Artists",
        "6": "Politicians"
    },
    "message": "Get data successfully."
}
```

I want to parse the above json.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Many ways to do it. You can use javas integrated json api or some external library (jackson, gson etc)

Comment: so far what you have done.whether you ar getting it from Api call or something else

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a good practice to keep numbers as key in your object,
I advise you to use a JsonArray

```
{
 "status":true,
 "message":"Get data successfully.",
 "data":[ "Business People", "Actors", "Musicians", "Sports People", "Artists" 
 ,"Politicians"]
}
```

and then use JsonArray to parse data

Answer (score 0):

Change your data to JSONArray as a set of JSONObject to perform dynamic job

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(your_string)
 JSONArray  data = json.getJsonArray("data");

 for(int i = 0;i<data.length();i++)
  {
   JSONObject item = data.getJSONObject(i);
   String itemString = item.getString(Integer.parseInt(i+1));
 /// do whatever you want ie : add itemString to a list
  }
```

Comment: actually response is dynamic.i want to parse "data" object like an array

Comment: So fo first have to create a jsonarray as data

Answer (score 0):

You may use [handy service](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) that generates you java model.

Then just use Gson to serialize-deserialize json.

However in your case that "1", "2", "3" etc may be fixed parameters, or dynamic Map.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Klaxon to parse the JSON 
https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon

Really easy usage:

```
Klaxon().parse<yourClass>(yourJsonAsString)
```

where yourClass is a data class with your parsing needs. See Klaxon documentation with for each of your needs. Comment if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this website https://quicktype.io/ it will help you in the creation of java models.

Now serialize and deserialize JSON by using GSON.

Add the following dependency
**implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'**

**Here is an example:**

public Car fromJson(){

```
String json = "{\"brand\":\"Jeep\", \"doors\": 3}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Car car = gson.fromJson(json, Car.class);
return car;
```

}